# Pygame Pause Functionality

Tags: python, class, pygame, pause

I've been trying to add a pause functionality to my pong game but it is not working. I can pause the game once and it stop, but then after that if I press the key which pauses the game, the game will move a few frames then stop. After that, I have to hold the pause button down to make the game move. I will link the class code below:

```
class Game:
    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start
        self.score1 = 0
        self.score2 = 0
        self.pause = False
        self.over = False

    def play(self, ai):
        player2.AI = ai
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
        self.over = False
        while self.start:
            # quits if x is pressed
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()
            pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            if pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]:
                self.pauseMenu()
            if self.pause == False:
                # creates list of pressed keys and using that to determine movement
                pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if pressed_keys[pygame.K_w]:
                    player1.moveUp(5)
                if pressed_keys[pygame.K_s]:
                    player1.moveDown(5)
                if player2.AI == True:
                    player2.AI_move(ball)
                if pressed_keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    pygame.quit()
                else:
                    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                        player2.moveUp(5)
                    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                        player2.moveDown(5)

                if pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]:
                    self.pauseMenu()

                # scoring system if ball touches variable, increments score and resets ball to middle
                if ball.rect.x >= 790:
                    self.score1 += 1
                    ball.rect.x = 400
                    ball.rect.y = 240
                    ball.x_velo = choice([-2, 2])
                    ball.y_velo = choice([-1, -2, 1, 2])
                if ball.rect.x <= 0:
                    self.score2 += 1
                    ball.rect.x = 400
                    ball.rect.y = 240
                    ball.x_velo = choice([-2, 2])
                    ball.y_velo = choice([-1, -2, 1, 2])

                # bounces ball of top or bottom wall
                if ball.rect.y > 470 or ball.rect.y < 0:
                    ball.y_velo = -ball.y_velo

                # detects collision and reflects ball off board
                if pygame.sprite.collide_mask(ball, player1) or pygame.sprite.collide_mask(ball, player2):
                    ball.bounce()

                # refresh method to move ball
                ball.refresh()
                # draws background and sprites onto screen each tick
                screen.fill(BLACK)
                pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [400, 0], [400, 580], 1)
                all_sprites_list.update()
                all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

                # draws score at top
                font = pygame.font.Font('ARCADECLASSIC.TTF', 74)
                text = font.render(str(self.score1), 1, BLUE)
                screen.blit(text, (300, 10))
                text = font.render(str(self.score2), 1, BLUE)
                screen.blit(text, (470, 10))
                if self.score1 >= 5:
                    self.victory("Player 1")
                elif self.score2 >= 5:
                    self.victory("Player 2")
                # refreshes display each tick
                pygame.display.flip()
                # sets number of ticks per second
                clock.tick(60)

    def victory(self, winner):
        pass

    def pauseMenu(self):
        if self.pause == True:
            self.pause = False
        elif self.pause == False:
            self.pause = True
```

Comment: better use `event` instead of `pressed_keys()`  because when you press button then it can run `pressed_keys()` thousand times - so `pause` will togle to `True` and next to `False` thousands times - but it will run only one `event`. If you add `print()` inside `if pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]:` then you will see thousand messages instead single one.

Comment: you can toggle pause in single  line `self.pause = not self.pause`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
pause=False
#your game code
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type==KEYUP:
            if event.key==K_p:
                pause = True

while pause == True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type==KEYUP:
                if event.key==K_p:
                    pause = False

#your remaining code
```

You first Make the pause false then add a key that pauses the screen.

Comment: is there anyway to do it without the pygame.event.get() method?

Comment: @Mason19Kelley without `event` you would have to remeber previous value from `pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]` and compare with current value from `pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]` - and if it changed from `False` to `True` then you would have to  change  `pause`. So you would have to do what you already have with `event`. You get `event` `KEYDOWN` only when it changes value from `True` to `False` and `KEYUP` when it changes value from `False` to `True`

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that code runs very fast and when you press button `P` then it runs loop many times and it checks `pressed_keys()` many times - so it executes `pauseMenu()` many times and it changes `pause` many times and you don't know if last value will be `True` or `False`. But you have to execute `pauseMenu()` only once.

You could use `event` for this because when you press button then system sends only one event and it will run `pauseMenu()` only runs.

```
        # quits if x is pressed
        for event in pygame.event.get():

            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                exit()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_p:
                    # toggle value 
                    self.pause = not self.pause
```

---

Using `pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]` you would have to remeber previous value `pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]` and compare it with current value `pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]` - and if it changed from `False` to `True` then you would have to change `pause`. So you would have to do what you already have with event.

```
# before loop

previus_key_p = False

# inside loop

pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if pressed_keys[pygame.K_p] and previus_key_p = False:
   self.pauseMenu()

previus_key_p = pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]
```

---

If you check button `P` before `if self.pause == False:` then you don't have to do this again inside `if self.pause == False:`

**EDIT:** After adding missing code I run code and the main problem was this second `if self.pause == False:`

---

**BTW:**

To toggle value `True/False` you can use `not`

```
def pauseMenu(self):
    self.pause = not self.pause
```

---

**BTW:**

Few times I saw similar problem when `pygame.mouse.get_button()` was used to press button on screen and after that there was displayed new button in the same place - it was pressing at once new button.

---

**EDIT:**

Minimal working code.

It needs functions to move players but ball is moving and you can pause it. It also display text when it is paused - I draw all outside `if not self.pause:` and draw text `Pause` but I could even draw some animation when it is paused.

I also renamed `ball.refresh()` into `ball.update()` and I add `ball` to group and now group runs `update()` for all objects.

I added comments with prefix `# <---`

```
import pygame
from random import choice

# --- constants --- (PEP8: UPPER_CASE_NAMES)

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLUE  = (0, 0, 255)

# --- classes --- (PEP8: CamelCaseNames)

class Game:

    def __init__(self, start):
        self.start = start
        self.score1 = 0
        self.score2 = 0
        self.pause = False
        self.over = False

    def play(self, ai):
        player2.AI = ai
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
        pygame.display.set_caption("Pong")
        self.over = False

        # <--- you can create it once
        #font = pygame.font.Font('ARCADECLASSIC.TTF', 74)
        font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, 74)
        
        # <--- value at start
        previous_key_p = False
        
        while self.start:
            # quits if x is pressed
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    pygame.quit()
                    exit()

            pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
            
            # <--- check also previous value
            if pressed_keys[pygame.K_p] and previous_key_p == False:
                self.pauseMenu()

            # <--- keep current value to check it in next loop
            previous_key_p = pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]

            if not self.pause:
                # creates list of pressed keys and using that to determine movement
                pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
                if pressed_keys[pygame.K_w]:
                    player1.moveUp(5)
                if pressed_keys[pygame.K_s]:
                    player1.moveDown(5)
                if player2.AI == True:
                    player2.AI_move(ball)
                if pressed_keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
                    pygame.quit()
                else:
                    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_UP]:
                        player2.moveUp(5)
                    if pressed_keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
                        player2.moveDown(5)

                # <--- you don't need it 
                #if pressed_keys[pygame.K_p]:
                #    self.pauseMenu()

                # scoring system if ball touches variable, increments score and resets ball to middle
                if ball.rect.x >= 790:
                    self.score1 += 1
                    ball.rect.x = 400
                    ball.rect.y = 240
                    ball.x_velo = choice([-2, 2])
                    ball.y_velo = choice([-1, -2, 1, 2])
                if ball.rect.x <= 0:
                    self.score2 += 1
                    ball.rect.x = 400
                    ball.rect.y = 240
                    ball.x_velo = choice([-2, 2])
                    ball.y_velo = choice([-1, -2, 1, 2])

                # bounces ball of top or bottom wall
                if ball.rect.y > 470 or ball.rect.y < 0:
                    ball.y_velo = -ball.y_velo

                # detects collision and reflects ball off board
                if pygame.sprite.collide_mask(ball, player1) or pygame.sprite.collide_mask(ball, player2):
                    ball.bounce()

                # <--- I renamed it to `update()` and add to group so I don't have to run it manually
                # refresh method to move ball
                #ball.update()

                all_sprites_list.update()

                if self.score1 >= 5:
                    self.victory("Player 1")
                elif self.score2 >= 5:
                    self.victory("Player 2")
    
            # <-- outside `pause` - so it can display animation also when paused
                            
            # --- only draws (without updates, etc.) --- 
            
            # draws background and sprites onto screen each tick
            screen.fill(BLACK)
            
            pygame.draw.line(screen, WHITE, [400, 0], [400, 580], 1)
            
            all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

            # draws score at top
            text1 = font.render(str(self.score1), 1, BLUE)
            screen.blit(text1, (300, 10))
            
            text2 = font.render(str(self.score2), 1, BLUE)
            screen.blit(text2, (470, 10))

            if self.pause:
                text = font.render('PAUSE', 1, RED)
                rect = text.get_rect()
                rect.center = screen.get_rect().center
                screen.blit(text, rect)
            
            # refreshes display each tick
            pygame.display.flip()
            
            # sets number of ticks per second
            clock.tick(60)

    def victory(self, winner):
        pass

    def pauseMenu(self):
        if self.pause == True:
            self.pause = False
        elif self.pause == False:
            self.pause = True

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((10,100))
        self.image.fill(GREEN)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask =  pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)

class Ball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.surface.Surface((10,10))
        self.image.fill(RED)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.mask =  pygame.mask.from_surface(self.image)
        
    # <--- I renamed `refresh` to `update()`         
    def update(self):        
        self.rect.x += 1
        
    def bounce(self):        
        pass

# --- functions --- (PEP8: lower_case_names)

# ... empty ...

# --- main ---
        
size = (800, 600)    

pygame.init()

player1 = Player()
player2 = Player()
ball = Ball()

all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group((player1, player2, ball))

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
Game(True).play(False)
```

Comment: I added minimal working code.

Comment: thank you so much! I have been struggling with this for a few days and was bottlenecking my project! the reason I did not want to use the event methods is because I am making an arcade machine for my freshman project with a RPi and eventually the input will be a button, so I can easily swap the pressed_keys input with the button input. Thanks again.

Comment: if you means button attached to RPI `gpio` then I think you can't catch it with `pressed_keys()`. Rather you would have to use module `gpio` for this. And maybe it can work similar to `events` :)